# How to use std::optional in C++

Tags: c++, functional-programming, monads, c++17

In C++17 `std::optional` is introduced, I was happy about this decision, until I looked at the [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). I know `Optional`/`Maybe` from Scala, Haskell and Java 8, where optional is a monad and follows monadic laws. This is not the case in the C++17 implementation. How am I supposed to use `std::optional`, whithout functions like `map` and `flatMap`/`bind`, whats the advantage using a `std::optional` vs for example returning `-1`, or a `nullptr` from a function if it fails to compute a result?
And more important for me, why wasn't `std::optional` designed to be a monad, is there a reason?

Comment: C++ is not Haskell.

Comment: What if -1 is a valid return value already?

Comment: If you return a `int` and return `-1` as failure that means `-1` cold never be a valid output for the input.  Most of the time you cannot do that.  As far as usage goes you shoud consult a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: You cannot return `nullptr` from a function whose return type is `int`.

Comment: The reference you linked has examples on how to use it.

Comment: @KerrekSB I understand the point of "C++ is not Haskell" but the optional type clearly comes from functional programming, so one could say, "returning a optional is not C++, just throw an exception"

Comment: "*but the optional type clearly comes from functional programming*" That may be the source of your confusion.

Comment: @Exagon: The `std::optional` is in direct lineage from Barton and Nackman's `Fallible` class. As far as I know their inspiration was not functional programming.

Comment: See also [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/optional/tutorial.html) (this page and the next one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How am I supposed to use std::optional, whithout functions like map and flatMap/bind

`Maybe` in Haskell is perfectly usable without `fmap`, it represents a value that may or may not be there. It also brings to the type system the distinction so you need to handle both cases.

> whats the advantage using a std::optional vs for example returning -1, or a nullptr from a function if it fails to compute a result?

How do you know what the error condition is? Is it `0`, `-1`, `MAX_INT`, `nullptr` or something else? If I have both a `unsigned int` and `int` return value and the `int` version previously returned `-1` should you change them both to `MAX_INT` or make them return different values? `std::optional` avoids the problem.

> And more important for me, why wasn't std::optional designed to be a monad, is there a reason?

Does C++ have monads at the moment? Until a different abstraction than the container one there isn't really a way to add that functionality.

Comment: I'd say that C++ does have monads in it (optional<T> and vector<T> for instance). What it lacks is nice syntax for doing monadic operations on them, but it can still be useful to think of them as monads.

Comment: @toth surely the operations (and the fact they obey monad laws) are the important part of the monad, rather than the type? Without the operations, optional<T> is just a type.

Answer (score 8):

There is [P0798r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0798r0.html) proposal with exactly this, and the associated implementation [here on Github](https://github.com/TartanLlama/optional). The proposal also refers to general monadic interface proposal, and similarly usable std::expected. Implementations of those are also available.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* define `bind` and `return` over `std::optional`, so in that sense it is still a Monad.

For instance, a possible `bind`

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::optional<T2> bind(std::optional<T1> a, std::function< std::optional<T2>(T1)> f) {
   if(a.has_value()) return f(a.value());
   return std::optional<T2>{};
 }
```

It is actually probably useful to define this.

As to why the standard library does not ship with this, or something like this, I think the answer is one of preferred style in the language.

Comment: This won't work. You want something along the lines of `template<typename T1, typename F> auto bind(std::optional<T1> a, F f) -> std::optional<std::decay_t<decltype(f(*a))>>;`

Comment: @T.C., it is true that in my version the compiler cannot deduce T2, so you have to specify it whenever you invoke bind, but I'd say that still counts as working. I agree than in practice your version is superior since it does type deduction and is more efficient (no need to use std::function if you don't want to), but at least to me it's harder to tell what the type of `f` is supposed to be from looking at the declaration.

Comment: @T.C., also I believe you don't want the `std::optional` on your trailing return type. The `f` in bind should return a `std::optional`, your type signature would be the right one for `fmap`.

Comment: Good point on the second. That's a mistype. (If you want explicitly specified parameters, at least swap your template parameter order and wrap the second function parameter's type in a non-deduced context so that `T1` can still be deduced.)